# "He acted expectedly" is correct, but is "He acted expected" also correct?

Tags: grammar

For some reason, I doubt the second form. I would rather use the first one. Googling for *acted expectedly* and *acted expected* shows that only the former is used.

But *expected* is an adjective, just like *strange* and *disorganized*, and it feels okay to say *He acted strange* and *He acted disorganized*.

Is there a rule that guides which adjective compliments *act* can take? Is this perhaps because *expected* has the adverb counterpart *expectedly*?

Comment: "He acted expectedly" sounds odd to me for some reason. "He acted unexpectedly" is fine, but without the "un-" prefix, I would prefer a phrasing like "He acted as expected".

Comment: *acted as expected*

Comment: @sumelic I certainly agree, but there seems to be better endorsement of the 'in the expected manner' sense of 'expectedly' (Collins) than of the 'in an unexpected manner' sense of 'unexpectedly'.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with "He acted expectedly", except for its lack of use. You can say "He acted predictably", and, as others have pointed out, "He acted as expected". As to why *expectedly* is not used, I have no idea.

Comment: I wasn't able to rationalize for myself why "He acted expected" is wrong, when other similar examples are fine.

Comment: I would understand "He acted expected" as meaning that he acted as if someone were expecting him.

Answer (score 1):

*acted expectedly* is correct, because *acted* is a verb, and you have to use an adverb to modify it.

The reason we can say *He acted strange* and *He acted disorganized* is because in this case *strange* and *disorganized* are actually describing the person, not the acting. These sentences can be viewed as short for *He acted as if he's strange/disorganized*. But you can't do this with *expected* because *expected* is not an adjective you can use to describe a person.

Comment: "He was expected at the party" really means "His presence was expected at the party". It's not really describing the person, but the person's status.

Comment: *expected* there is a verb, not an adjective. It's something everyone was doing. In fact, that can also be an explanation for "He was expected at the party" -- it's a verb in the passive form.

Answer (score 0):

As for *expected* as a subject complement, consider:

> The bad weather was expected, it wasn't something that surprised them.
>
> John was not an uninvited guest. People were waiting for him. He  was expected.

It is not a stretch to come up with

> Was John  expected at the party? I dunno. He acted expected.

This can be compared to

> Was John prepared at the seminar? I dunno. He acted prepared.

The *grammar* of the sentences is the same.

The ellipsis of *as if he were* between 'acted' and 'expected' or 'prepared' is legitimate in this truncated form. It may not be something we say everyday (I can't find any hits on Google books)  but there's nothing inherently ungrammatical about it.

> He acted strange.

Here, *strange* can be analysed as either a flat adverb equal to *strangely* (akin to the Apple slogan  *think different*, which certain grammarians insist is a corruption of *think differently*) or as an adjective modifying John (akin to *He was strange*).

In *He acted expected*, *expected* is not a flat adverb. It means something different to *He acted expectedly*.

Dearth of usage does make something ungrammatical. There are only two unique usages of *acted expectedly* in Google books:

> Even as De Klerk acted expectedly, the incident has tinted his presidency.
>
> Women writers in America have acted expectedly also.

The OED lists  *expectedly* as an adverb and gives a 2008 usage:

> Poverty among Southeast Asian families remained expectedly high.

---

Or consider:

> John thought (of) himself (as)  prepared.

This can "collapse" to

John thought himself prepared.

and

> John thought (of) himself (as) expected.

This can be rendered as

> John thought himself expected.

No one else may have thought John expected at the party, but this doesn't mean that John can't think of himself as expected.